# How do you convert between Substrate specific types and Rust primitive types?

Tags: rust, blockchain, substrate

Using the Substrate blockchain framework, how can I convert between Substrate specific types and Rust primitive types and vice versa?

For example:

- Convert a time (`T::Moment`) to a `u64`
- Convert a u64 to a `T::Balance`

etc...

Comment: Did you manage to achieve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## For the latest in Substrate master

Substrate has [removed `As`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/2602) in favor of `From`/`Into`. **An assumption is made that all types are at least `u32`.**

From the trait `SimpleArithmatic`, the following are implemented:

- `From`: `u8`, `u16`, `u32`
- `TryFrom`: `u64`, `u128`, `usize`
- `TryInto`: `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64`, `u128`, `usize`

Another trait is also provided to provide ergonomic
infallible conversion when you don't care if the value saturates.

- `UniqueSaturatedInto`: `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64`, `u128`
- `UniqueSaturatedFrom`: `u64`, `u128`

> **NOTE on `SaturatedConversion` from Gav**
>
> `SaturatedConversion` (`saturated_into` and `saturated_from`) should not be used unless you know what you're doing, you've thought and considered all options and your use-case implies that saturation is fundamentally correct. The only time I imagine this is the case is deep in runtime arithmetic where you are logically certain it will not overflow, but can't provide a proof because it would depend on consistent pre-existing state.

This means that working from `u32` to Substrate specific types should be easy:

```rust
pub fn u32_to_balance(input: u32) -> T::Balance {
    input.into()
}
```

For larger types, you need to handle the case where the `Balance` type for a runtime is smaller than what is available:

```rust
pub fn u64_to_balance_option(input: u64) -> Option<T::Balance> {
    input.try_into().ok()
}

// Note the warning above about saturated conversions
pub fn u64_to_balance_saturated(input: u64) -> T::Balance {
    input.saturated_into()
}
```

When converting from `T::Balance` to a rust primitive, you need to also handle conversion between incompatible types:

```
pub fn balance_to_u64(input: T::Balance) -> Option<u64> {
    TryInto::<u64>::try_into(input).ok()
}

// Note the warning above about saturated conversions
pub fn balance_to_u64_saturated(input: T::Balance) -> u64 {
    input.saturated_into::<u64>()
}
```

---

## For Substrate v1.0

Substrate provides [`pub trait As<T>` in the `sr-primitives` crate](https://substrate.dev/rustdocs/v1.0/sr_primitives/traits/trait.As.html):

```
/// Simple trait similar to `Into`, except that it can be used to convert numerics between each
/// other.
pub trait As<T> {
    /// Convert forward (ala `Into::into`).
    fn as_(self) -> T;
    /// Convert backward (ala `From::from`).
    fn sa(_: T) -> Self;
}
```

Here are some working examples of how it can be used:

```rust
impl<T: Trait> Module<T> {
    // `as_` will turn T::Balance into a u64
    pub fn balance_to_u64(input: T::Balance) -> u64 {
        input.as_()
    }

    // Being explicit, you can convert a `u64` to a T::Balance
    // using the `As` trait, with `T: u64`, and then calling `sa`
    pub fn u64_to_balance(input: u64) -> T::Balance {
        <T::Balance as As<u64>>::sa(input)
    }

    // You can also let Rust figure out what `T` is
    pub fn u64_to_balance_implied(input: u64) -> T::Balance {
        <T::Balance as As<_>>::sa(input)
    }

    // You can also let Rust figure out where `sa` is implemented
    pub fn u64_to_balance_implied_more(input: u64) -> T::Balance {
        T::Balance::sa(input)
    }
}
```

Comment: [Better to avoid `As` and use `From/Into`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/1377).

Comment: This will be soon slightly changed with this PR https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/4517

Comment: Has anyone been able to convert substrate blocknumber to let's say a u8?

Comment: You can do it with `saturated_into()`, but as soon as your block number is past 255, the value returned would be stuck at 255, and probably not very useful.

Answer (score 2):

here are few examples which should help in conversion of number to Balance Type:

```
//declare following import
use frame_support::sp_runtime::traits::Zero;
use frame_support::sp_runtime::SaturatedConversion;

//then saturated_into can be used to convert number into Balance type as follows
let cost_in_u64: u64 = 250; //or expression like 200 + 50;
let cost: BalanceOf<T> = cost_in_u64.saturated_into::<BalanceOf<T>>();

//convert 1010 of type u32 into Balance
let cost2: BalanceOf<T> = 1010u32.into();
//set zero balance
let cost3 = BalanceOf::<T>::zero();
```

where BalanceOf is defined in cfg as follows

```
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
type BalanceOf<T> =
        <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;
```