# Timestamp Arithmetic in Substrate

Tags: substrate

I can get the current timestamp as `<timestamp::Module<T>>::get()` in substrate runtime module.

How can I perform basic arithmetic (addition, substraction) with it?

```rust
decl_module! {
  pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {
    fn deposit_event<T>() = default;

    pub fn func1(origin) -> Result {
      let now = <timestamp::Module<T>>::get();
      const DURATION = 60 * 5;
      // what is the proper way of performing the following operation?
      // let future = now + DURATION; 

      // At some point in future, can I perform the following comparison?
      if now > future { 
        // ... some code 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Further Question**:

This brings out a question I am not sure about Rust / Rust doc. Type [`T::Moment`](https://crates.parity.io/srml_timestamp/trait.Trait.html#associatedtype.Moment) has to have trait [`SimpleArithmetic`](https://crates.parity.io/sr_primitives/traits/trait.SimpleArithmetic.html), which in turns require the type has trait `TryInto<u32>`.

So this should work,

```
let tmp: u32 = DURATION + now.try_into()?;
```

but actually returning:

```
error[E0277]: cannot add `()` to `u32`
| no implementation for `u32 + ()`
|
= help: the trait `core::ops::Add<()>` is not implemented for `u32`

error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<() as core::convert::TryFrom<<T as srml_timestamp::Trait>::Moment>>::Error == &str`
| note: expected type `core::convert::Infallible`
=               found type `&str`
```

**Further Question - 2**

Basically, I went through [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081117/how-do-you-convert-between-substrate-specific-types-and-rust-primitive-types). Could you post an example how to convert from `Timestamp` to `u32`/`u64`, and from `u32`/`u64` to `Timestamp`, and what additional modules need to be brought in?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out how to use `into()`, `try_into()`, `from()`, `try_from()`.

But from Shawn example and what Bryan said to avoid, I can convert timestamp to u64 easily by: `now.as_()`.

If anyone can show me the answer using `into()`, `from()` or its variant, I will be happy to update this thread and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: The `into()` and `from()` stuff is only in Substrate v2.0 and later. If you are using Substrate v1.0, this is where you might be struggling.