# How to convert u128 to Balance?

Tags: substrate, polkadot

How to convert u128 to Balance?

```
use frame_support::{
        traits::{Currency, ExistenceRequirement, Get, ReservableCurrency, WithdrawReasons},
    };

type BalanceOf<T> = <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<AccountIdOf<T>>>::Balance;

#[pallet::type_value]
pub fn DefaultRegistrationFees<T: Config>() -> BalanceOf<T> { 100 }
```

Error:
lib.rs(79, 67): expected associated type, found integer

Tried this method: [How do you convert between Substrate specific types and Rust primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081117/how-do-you-convert-between-substrate-specific-types-and-rust-primitive-types)

100.into() doesn't work.

Will I have to declare on runtime using [configurable pallet constant](https://substrate.dev/recipes/constants.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With this https://crates.parity.io/sp_arithmetic/traits/trait.SaturatedConversion.html#method.saturated_into you can easily cast num to `Balance`.

Example https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/paritytech/substrate/-/blob/frame/transaction-payment/src/lib.rs?L584.

Also, recommend to read this [How do you convert between Substrate specific types and Rust primitive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081117/how-do-you-convert-between-substrate-specific-types-and-rust-primitive-types?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1):

here are few examples which should help in conversion of number of type u128 to Balance Type:

```
//declare following import
use frame_support::sp_runtime::SaturatedConversion;

//then saturated_into can be used to convert number into Balance type as follows
let cost_in_u128: u128 = 250; //or expression like 200 + 50;
let cost: BalanceOf<T> = cost_in_u128.saturated_into::<BalanceOf<T>>();

//convert 1010 of type u32 into Balance
let cost2: BalanceOf<T> = 1010u32.into();
//set zero balance
let cost3 = BalanceOf::<T>::zero();
```

where BalanceOf is defined in cfg as follows

```
#[cfg(feature = "std")]
type BalanceOf<T> =
        <<T as Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance;
```